# Android device discovery by another device using JmDNS

Tags: android, jmdns

I used JmDNS to discover linux machines from android devices and vice versa.

They seemed to work well.

But I am unable to discover an android device using another one even after I have acquired the multicast lock before creating and registering `jmdns`.
Here is my sample code :-

```
lock.setReferenceCounted(true);
lock.acquire();
.....
jmdns = JmDNS.create(ipAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any code, I won't be able to debug, I am just putting this link here : https://vshivam.wordpress.com/2015/02/15/using-jmdns-for-service-advertisement-and-discovery-on-android/